# Connect to oracle cloud database by wallet in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oracle, cloud, node-oracledb

I have scripts that i need to run, to precise it is `CREATE TABLE` script.
I have such functions, see below:

oracleLoader.ts

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
import dbConfig from "./oracleDBConfig";
import log from "../utils/winston";

function oracleLoader(sql: string) {

  const connection = oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

  try{
    connection.execute(sql);
    log.info("Table created.");
  } catch (e) {
    log.error("SQL script do not executed!" + e);
  }

}

export default oracleLoader;
```

oracleDBConfig.ts

```
function oracleDBConfig() {
  return {
    user: mail,
    password: pass,
    connectString: str
  };
}

export default oracleDBConfig;
```

Where to get that username or do i need email?

Where to get password, is it password from database, or from oracle account?

Where to get connection string?

What if i have my .zip file with oracle-wallet.

Remember that i need to connect to the database that existing in the cloud.

Note: in line `const connection = oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);` i have a warning that:

`Argument type () => {password: string, user: string, connectString: string} is not assignable to parameter type GetConnectionOptions`

Comment: Did you check [the documentation first](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbp/connect-node-js.html#GUID-C949813D-A2E2-404F-B863-32BBD2385778)? What is the issue with it?

Comment: @astentx yes, i did, currently the problem is in the last note, why i'm getting that issue with datatypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username and password you need are the Database username and password.  Assuming you're using Oracle Autonomous DB, then the administration username is 'ADMIN' (and you can use this to create other users).  The connection string will be the alias in the tnsnames.ora file that you download in the zip file with the wallet.

Since this seems new to you, Oracle's 'quick start' is a handy place to begin https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/quickstartnodejs.html

The 'not assignable' error is a different issue, not related to Oracle.  First you need to call `dbConfig()` to get the credentials.  Then you need somehow to work with the async oracledb functions.  Then you should add some error handling.

I'm not a typescript user, but this runs:

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
import dbConfig from "./oracleDBConfig";

async function oracleLoader(sql: string) {

    let connection;
    try {
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig());
        const r = await connection.execute(sql);
        console.log(r);
        console.log("SQL statement was executed!");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("SQL statement was not executed!" + e);
    } finally {
        if (connection) {
            try {
                await connection.close();
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
}

export default oracleLoader;
```

Note that `execute()` executes a single statement, not a script.

In real life, you probably want to use a connection pool, see the node-oracledb [connection pooling](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpooling) documentation.

Comment: Since that execute() executes only a single statement, therefore, i should go through the script by iterations, am i right?

Comment: If you are executing a sequence of statements, then you will need to execute them individually.  You would also want to open a connection once, then execute all statements - do not open a connection for each statement.